# Keyword detection from a query

Tags: search, nlp, pattern-matching, information-retrieval

I have a database full of keywords Where each keyword could be a phrase (collection of words), and when I send a query, I want to match all possible keywords in the query. I am wondering how this could be effectively done. The problems I am facing are

- The query could have one or more keywords.
- The match needn't be exact (could be a close match).

I went through this [question and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70560/how-do-i-compare-phrases-for-similarity), but again, I am not sure how I could be grouping words in the query to form phrases which could be compared to each keyword in the database. There could be n(n+1)/2 phrases which could be formed for a query with n words. So the simplest solution is to compare each of this phrase with every keyword in the database and find matches.
Is there a better solution? Are there standard algorithms/libraries to do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Build an index of the database using your favorite search engine library, e.g. [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/)
2. Run a query

Search engine packages commonly have lots of fuzzy matching options. Lucene even has a [spell checker](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/SpellChecker) that can map a word to similar words.